# Why is VB flamed for being easy and yet Python is not?

Tags: python, vb.net

I have always wondered about this and seen this among lots of programmers. Why is a VB programmer or VB code easily dismissed as too noobish and easy while the same does not apply to Python or Python code? After all, isn't Python as easy as VB is? And it does provide drag-n-drop GUI application building also. So why is it that VB is flamed and yet Python is not?

I am just wondering out of curiosity.

Comment: VB is not flamed for being easy. Why would anybody flame a language for being easy?

Comment: @K Anderson: Not related, but I personally steer clear of any language wars. They are not worth it and big waste of time, imo.

Comment: @daniels: I have seen it lots of times. VB code is dismissed as too easy and VB programmers are called bad programmers cause they are apparently not smart enough. Yet this doesn't apply to Python.

Comment: Partly the blame may be due to VB's history. In any case, you may consider programmers.stackexchange.com for this question as it might be inappropriate here. At least consider making it a community wiki as it pretty subjective and could potentially get closed otherwise

Comment: If somebody is flaming a language and claiming that any programmers who use it are by default bad programmers and not smart enough to use another language, it sounds like you've found someone to whom you shouldn't listen.

Comment: Maybe because Python is more powerfull programming language.

Comment: There are many reasons to flame a language, but being easy is not one of them. Whoever is talking VB down for you should use another excuse.

Comment: Back in 2001 [Joel said](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000006.html) "Many VB6 programs are spaghetti, either because they're quick and dirty one-offs, or because they're written by hack programmers without training... [but] if you take top-notch C++ programmers who dream in pointers, and let them code in VB6... they become super-efficient coding machines... I've spent years writing code for C++/MFC and years writing code in Visual Basic, and VB6 is just much, much more productive" So there were good programmers using VB6. Dismissing all VB6 programmers is just prejudice

Answer (score 7):

VB is flamed less for being easy than for the population of programmers who use it.  VB is perceived as being for people one step up from writing Excel macros, often in in-house corporate environments, churning out crapware. Being a Microsoft product doesn't help.

VB is also seen as being the low-end language in the Microsoft ecosystem, with an ad-hoc design.

Python, on the other hand is open source, and cool because it is used in scientific applications, web startups, etc.

I'm not defending these positions, just giving you the perspective I've seen.  As others have said, language wars are usually pointless.  Occasionally you'll get a discussion that will truly touch on interesting differences between languages, but usually not.